# flutter_callkit_incoming: getting error while showing app notification on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, call, callkit

I am using package : flutter_callkit_incoming: ^1.0.3+3
for showing call notifications. I have used the code in the documentation as mentioned.

I am getting following error when I use "AppIcon" as Icon name in iOS Params.
AppIcon folder contains all the app icons
I get same error when I create CallKitIcon folder as given in their example and then I still get the same error

I have tried lowering the version to 1.0.2+2 but still getting the same error

```
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
    frame #0: 0x000000018bd65c04 libswiftCore.dylib`_swift_runtime_on_report
libswiftCore.dylib`:
->  0x18bd65c04 <+0>: ret
libswiftCore.dylib`:
    0x18bd65c08 <+0>: b      0x18bd65c04               ; _swift_runtime_on_report
libswiftCore.dylib`:
    0x18bd65c0c <+0>: adrp   x8, 378792
    0x18bd65c10 <+4>: ldrb   w0, [x8, #0x744]
Target 0: (Runner) stopped.
Lost connection to device.
Exited
```

The code I am using is,

```
final params = CallKitParams(
    id: 'uuid',
    nameCaller: 'Hien Nguyen',
    appName: 'Callkit',
    avatar: 'https://i.pravatar.cc/100',
    handle: '0123456789',
    type: 0,
    duration: 30000,
    textAccept: 'Accept',
    textDecline: 'Decline',
    textMissedCall: 'Missed call',
    textCallback: 'Call back',
    extra: <String, dynamic>{'userId': '1a2b3c4d'},
    headers: <String, dynamic>{'apiKey': 'Abc@123!', 'platform': 'flutter'},
    android: AndroidParams(
      isCustomNotification: true,
      isShowLogo: false,
      isShowCallback: true,
      isShowMissedCallNotification: true,
      ringtonePath: 'system_ringtone_default',
      backgroundColor: '#0955fa',
      backgroundUrl: 'assets/test.png',
      actionColor: '#4CAF50',
    ),
    ios: IOSParams(
      iconName: 'CallKitLogo',
      handleType: '',
      supportsVideo: true,
      maximumCallGroups: 2,
      maximumCallsPerCallGroup: 1,
      audioSessionMode: 'default',
      audioSessionActive: true,
      audioSessionPreferredSampleRate: 44100.0,
      audioSessionPreferredIOBufferDuration: 0.005,
      supportsDTMF: true,
      supportsHolding: true,
      supportsGrouping: false,
      supportsUngrouping: false,
      ringtonePath: 'system_ringtone_default',
    ),
  );
  await FlutterCallkitIncoming.showCallkitIncoming(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

It was throwing error cause I changed id to use a string which was not uuid
By changing id = Uuid().v4() , it started working

Answer (score 0):

It was throwing error cause I changed id to use a string which was not uuid By changing id = UUID().uuidString

let data = flutter_callkit_incoming.Data(id: UUID().uuidString, nameCaller: nameCaller, handle: handle, type: 0)